# Spring-Retry circuit breaker moves to recover code, without any retry attempt in case of exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-retry

I am using the spring-retry library for my spring boot application.
When using `@CircuitBreaker(include = { Exception.class }, maxAttempts = 2)`

 annotation in case of exception the method moves to recover block, without any retry attempt.

Please find below the code snippet.
Full code is on GitHub, below is the link.
https://github.com/konduruvijaykumar/spring-retry-hystrix/tree/master/spring-retry-hystrix-service-1

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EnableRetry
public class SpringRetryHystrixService1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringRetryHystrixService1Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

```java
@RestController
public class SpringRetryHystrixService1SimpleController {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    SpringRetryHystrixService1SimpleService springRetryHystrixService1SimpleService;

    @GetMapping("/simple-retry-cb-getint")
    public int retryCircuitBreakerGetInt() throws Exception {
        return springRetryHystrixService1SimpleService.getRetryCircuitBrreakerIntService();
    }

}
```

```java
@Service
public class SpringRetryHystrixService1SimpleService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Recover
    private int recoverFromException(Exception exception) {
        log.info(" ## recoverFromException(Exception exception) ##");
        return 0;
    }

    @CircuitBreaker(include = { Exception.class }, maxAttempts = 2)
    public int getRetryCircuitBrreakerIntService() throws Exception {
        log.info(" ## getRetryCircuitBrreakerIntService() ##");
        if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
            Thread.sleep(1000 * 3);
            throw new RuntimeException("Service failed when executing getRetryIntService() method");
        }
        // One is success and Zero is failure
        return 1;
    }

}
```

I was expecting to see retry attempts, but only recover method was executed in case of exception.

Comment: CircuitBreaker and Retry both implementations are different.

Comment: @Sambit I did not understand. I am only using CircuitBreaker implementation here. This has attributes for retry maxAttempts (maximum number of attempts (including the first failure), defaults to 3). CircuitBreaker is itself annotated with Retryable(stateful = true)

Comment: I am saying, you donot need EnableRetry annotation if you are using CircuitBreaker.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is what Sambit answered to you, the annotated method getRetryCircuitBrreakerIntService with @CircuitBreaker must have the same signature as the @Recover annotated one.